# Como posso gerar um numero Inteiro em python utilizando Random

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Estou com o seguinte código e preciso que o resultado seja um numero do tipo inteiro, porem esta retornando um valor aleatório(numero ou none) com tipo aleatório (int ou nonetype)

```
from random import randint


def chave2():

    final = ((3-1)*(7-1))
    np = randint(2, final-1, 1) #Esta gerando tipos aleatórios para np
    cont = 0
    for x in range(1, np+1):
        if np % x == 0:
            cont += 1
    if cont == 2 and final % np != 0:
        return np
    else:
        chave2()

print(type(chave2()))

print(chave2())
```

ps:Já tentei usar diversas IDEs e versões diferentes tmb, estou usando a versão 3.7.4

Comment: `randint` leva 2 argumentos `randint(start, end)` e não 3 !

Answer (score 0):

Nessa linha `np = randint(2, final-1, 1)` a função `randint` deveria receber apenas 2 argumentos, gerando erro durante a execução. Então deveria ser alterada para `np = randint(2, final-1)`, com apenas dois argumentos sendo passados. Se forem realmente necessários os três argumentos, talvez você queira usar [`randrange(start, stop\[, step\])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

Outra coisa necessária é que você adicione um `return` à declaração else.

Depois das alterações fica:

```
from random import randint

def chave2():

  final = ((3-1)*(7-1))
  np = randint(2, final-1) #mudança
  print(np, final, 't', type(np))
  cont = 0
  for x in range(1, np+1):
    if np % x == 0:
      cont += 1
  if cont == 2 and final % np != 0:
      return np
  else:
    return chave2() # mudança

print(type(chave2()))

print(chave2())
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, estava utilizando os três argumentos em uma função randrange, porem as mudanças deram certo